# How can I include another parameter in my node.js web service?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Sorry if it's a tedious question, I'm just at the very beginning of understanding how JS/node.js works with post/get messages.

I'm writing a web service to query data from mongodb database based on the latitude/longitude and distance of the user. I wrote in my frontend code a following function:

```
// Take query parameters and incorporate into a JSON queryBody
    $scope.queryUsersFromLast24Hours = function(){

        // Assemble Query Body
        queryBody = {
            longitude: parseFloat($scope.formData.longitude),
            latitude: parseFloat($scope.formData.latitude),
            distance: parseFloat($scope.formData.distance)
        };


        // Post the queryBody to the /query POST route to retrieve the filtered results
        $http.post('/queryUsersFromLast24Hours', queryBody)

            // Store the filtered results in queryResults
            .success(function(queryResults){

                console.log(JSON.stringify(queryBody));

                // Pass the filtered results to the Google Map Service and refresh the map
                gservice.refresh(queryBody.latitude, queryBody.longitude, queryResults);

                // Count the number of records retrieved for the panel-footer
                $scope.queryCount = queryResults.length;
            })
            .error(function(queryResults){
                console.log('Error ' + queryResults);
            })
    };
```

and it calls the method `/queryUsersFromLast24Hours` from my backed code, which looks as follows:

```
// Retrieves JSON records for all users who meet a certain set of query conditions
    app.post('/queryUsersFromLast24Hours/', function(req, res){

        // Grab all of the query parameters from the body.
        var lat             = req.body.latitude;
        var long            = req.body.longitude;
        var distance        = req.body.distance;
        var dateNow           = new Date(); //right now



        // Opens a generic Mongoose Query. Depending on the post body we will...
        var query = User.find({});

        // ...include filter by Max Distance (converting miles to meters)
        if(distance){

            // Using MongoDB's geospatial querying features. (Note how coordinates are set [long, lat]
            query = query.where('location').near({ center: {type: 'Point', coordinates: [long, lat]},

                // Converting meters to miles. Specifying spherical geometry (for globe)
                maxDistance: distance * 1609.34, spherical: true});
        }
            console.log(dateNow);
            dateNow.setHours(dateNow.getHours()-24); //24 hours from now
            console.log(dateNow);
            query = query.where('created_at').gte(dateNow); //gte - greater then equal


        // Execute Query and Return the Query Results
        query.exec(function(err, users){
            if(err)
                res.send(err);

            // If no errors, respond with a JSON of all users that meet the criteria
            res.json(users);
        });
    });
```

But now, if I want to make it more universal and return the data not from the last 24 hours, but from the last xx hours given by the user, how should I modify it?

I want to create a webservice that will get not only lat/long/distance data, but also a number of hours as a POST message and returns the json with correct data. So how should I modify my frontend/backend code to include this change?

Also, right now I call it from the gui as follows:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="queryUsersFromLast24Hours()">Show data from last hour</button>
```

So how can I modify it also to pass a specific number of hours that will be included in the backend query search?

Thank you very much for help!

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you are going to subtract always a number X of hours, first I would recommend to change the name of your webService like : queryUsersFromLastNHours

Supposing you are going to trigger that request through a button click, then you may use a call like this

```
<button id='myButton' ng-click="queryUsersFromLast24Hours()">MyButton</button>
<input id="numberOfHours" ng-bind="hoursToSubtract" />
```

In angularJs, you must bind that type of values to the Controller via $scope. Then you will have in your Controller a fuction like this

```
$scope.hours = 0;

var $scope.formData.hours = function() {

    var hours = $scope.hours;

    var queryBody = {
        longitude: parseFloat($scope.formData.longitude),
        latitude: parseFloat($scope.formData.latitude),
        distance: parseFloat($scope.formData.distance),
        hoursToSubtract: hours
    };

    $http.post('/queryUsersFromLast24Hours', queryBody) ....

}
```

Read the [ngBind documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBind) for a better understanding

And finally in your nodeJs code, change

```
dateNow.setHours(dateNow.getHours()-24);
```

for

```
var n = req.body.hoursToSubtract;

if (n != null) {
    dateNow.setHours(dateNow.getHours()-n);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, can you tell me why did you write `5` here: `hoursToSubtract: 5` ? Also, now in my gui I call it from a button click `ng-click="queryUsersFromLast24Hours()"` - can I just pass a parameter somehow here in brackets?

Comment: I gave you an example for it. 5 is an arbitrary number. This '5' represents the number you are going to send to the server. I am going to edit the example to show you a better example

Comment: You can pass an arbitrary parameter yes, but I imagine this is not what you want. In any case, you can make something like this `ng-click="queryUsersFromLast24Hours(5)"` , and of course you must receive it as a parameter in your function

Answer (score 0):

Quick answer:

Front end:

```
// Take query parameters and incorporate into a JSON queryBody
$scope.queryUsers = function(){

    // Assemble Query Body
    queryBody = {
        longitude: parseFloat($scope.formData.longitude),
        latitude: parseFloat($scope.formData.latitude),
        distance: parseFloat($scope.formData.distance)
        hours : Number($scope.formData.hours)
    };


    // Post the queryBody to the /query POST route to retrieve the filtered results
    $http.post('/queryUsers', queryBody)

        // Store the filtered results in queryResults
        .success(function(queryResults){

            console.log(JSON.stringify(queryBody));

            // Pass the filtered results to the Google Map Service and refresh the map
            gservice.refresh(queryBody.latitude, queryBody.longitude, queryResults);

            // Count the number of records retrieved for the panel-footer
            $scope.queryCount = queryResults.length;
        })
        .error(function(queryResults){
            console.log('Error ' + queryResults);
        })
};
```

Back end:

```
// Retrieves JSON records for all users who meet a certain set of query conditions
app.post('/queryUsers/', function(req, res){

    // Grab all of the query parameters from the body.
    var lat             = req.body.latitude;
    var long            = req.body.longitude;
    var distance        = req.body.distance;
    var hours           = req.body.hours
    var dateNow         = new Date(); //right now



    // Opens a generic Mongoose Query. Depending on the post body we will...
    var query = User.find({});

    // ...include filter by Max Distance (converting miles to meters)
    if(distance){

        // Using MongoDB's geospatial querying features. (Note how coordinates are set [long, lat]
        query = query.where('location').near({ center: {type: 'Point', coordinates: [long, lat]},

            // Converting meters to miles. Specifying spherical geometry (for globe)
            maxDistance: distance * 1609.34, spherical: true});
    }
        console.log(dateNow);
        dateNow.setHours(dateNow.getHours()- hours); // XX hours from now
        console.log(dateNow);
        query = query.where('created_at').gte(dateNow); //gte - greater then equal


    // Execute Query and Return the Query Results
    query.exec(function(err, users){
        if(err)
            res.send(err);

        // If no errors, respond with a JSON of all users that meet the criteria
        res.json(users);
    });
});
```

Sorry if I am misunderstanding your question but just I want to give you some tips, this query looks like a GET instead of a POST, and you can use query params or path params.

Comment: Thanks! I asked similar question in a comment above, but maybe you will be able to answer me for it :) now in my gui I call it from a button click `ng-click="queryUsersFromLast24Hours()" `- can I just pass a parameter somehow here in brackets?

Answer (score 0):

Front end:

```
$http.post('/recentUsers?numHours=24', queryBody)
```

Back end:

```
 var numberOfHours;
 if (req.query.numHours) {
   try {
     numberOfHours = parseInt(req.query.numHours)
   } catch(e) {}
 }
 numberOfHours = numberOfHours || 24; // default to 24 hours.
 dateNow.setHours(dateNow.getHours() - numberOfHours)
```